# Print src attribute returning null, Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, driver, src

I had a bit of coding I did last month, and I returned to it today to find that the same function was now returning an empty 'src' when I ran the code. I'm supremely baffled as to what changed.

My relevant code:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/jones/Downloads/chromedriver')

    driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/pauljgarner/')

    images=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//img[@id="ember1216"] | //img[@id="ember1808"]')
    sleep(5)
    for image in images:
        print(images.get_attribute('src'))
        url = images.get_attribute('src')
```

I saw some posts that suggested the issue was that I needed the page to fully load and insert coding that has an implicit or explicit wait time. However, I did the code line by line in ipython, so the timing cannot be the issue -- the src was still returning a null.

Any idea of what is happening here? I know that there is an image, and that my xpath is correct. So, there must be a relevant src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change images to image inside your loop.

```
 for image in images:
        print(image.get_attribute('src'))
        url = image.get_attribute('src')
```

But looking at the page html, I was not able to find any elements with an img tag with the id's that you are trying to use.  Which images are you trying to find?